# Exporting list of attributes from multiple layers within extent in QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers, fields-attributes, export, overlapping-features

I'm looking for a way to export attributed values from multiple layers in a project from features within the extent of a specific polygon (project area).

So, for example, I have a polygon layer with soil classes, and a polygon layer with geomorphology classes and I'd like to export (for example to a CSV or Excel table) the attributes from those layers that intersect with the polygon of a project area. How is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Run the ["Extract/clip by extent"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#extract-clip-by-extent) geoalgorithm in [a batch processing](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/training_manual/processing/batch_conversion.html?highlight=batch%20processing#the-batch-processing-interface).

Comment: ... and export/save resulting layer as CSV